# Which anime do these figures of girls wearing idol-like uniform belong to?

Tags: merchandise

[image: girl 1]
[image: girl 2]
[image: girl 3]

I had come across this action figure when I was Japan, but was unable to find the character name.

Please help me out and if possible, give a description of the characters.

Comment: Welcome to [anime.se]. Could you add some more context on where did you take this photo, and any reasons why you think this is from an anime? [Merchandise identification is on-topic, but it needs more context to be acceptable on here](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4143/2516). Also, consider taking a quick [tour] to understand how this site works. Thank you.

Comment: @AkiTanaka unlike cosplay, I think it's relatively easier to know for action figure to be from anime or not. Like in this case, it's pretty clear that it's from anime just by looking at it. But maybe OP can explain where did they find it or is there any description in the box or something similar that can help us find this anime

Comment: @Darjeeling "*I think it's relatively easier to know for action figure to be from anime or not.*" hopefully that's the case, unlike asking for [original character figures on WonFes](https://myfigurecollection.net/blog/39237) without mentioning they're from WonFes :)

Answer (score 10):

These are characters from the gacha mobile rhythm game *THE iDOLM@STER CINDERELLA GIRLS*, a rhythm game spin-off of *THE iDOLM@STER* franchise. Unlike its counterpart *THE iDOLM@STER: Million Live!*, it features a completely original idol line-up, with the original characters of the franchise only making guest appearances in events.

The game also got an anime adaptation that ran for 2 seasons, the characters shown here were part of the ensemble of 14 idols selected to star in the adaptation, these 14 characters were shown in the adaptation as girls that were scouted for the Cinderella Project ran by the Producer. Other idols in the game also make an appearance as already established idols, making them all senior to the 14 newbies.

The figures you shared depict Moroboshi Kirara, Kanzaki Ranko and Mimura Kanako in the outfit they used for the Opening Theme for the 1st season of the anime. This outfit was used as well for the final concert shown at the end of the 2nd Season.

**Moroboshi Kirara** is a tall girl with a deep love for cutesy things, which goes to show in her burikko-like speech patterns. She does have a complex about her height being a mismatch with her personality but she's really optimistic as well which tends to hold back her complex.

**Kanzaki Ranko**, the fallen angel, a chuunibyou-style idol. She has trouble being honest which is why she hides behind her "fallen angel" persona, down to her everyday speech. Incidentally, she's no good with horror.

**Mimura Kanako**, a slightly chubby girl who loves sweets. She keeps worrying about her diet, but can't seem to be able to stick to them. A happy-go-lucky cinnamon roll.